# React Native Video Through HDMI Only

Tags: react-native, video-streaming

Phones have the ability to have connector, ie USB-C, attach HDMI cords and video or music be played through the HDMI connection to another device, ie projector.

Is there a way using react native to when media is played, have is NOT played on the screen and only through outputs such as the USB-C?

Comment: This is undoubtedly going to be platform-specific.  Are you targeting Android-only?  (Also, just a side note, not all phones support DisplayPort or HDMI alternative mode over USB-C.  I say this as an annoyed owner of a Google Pixel who would really like this feature. :-) )